# How to set language in bash script

Tags: bash, macos, localization

In MacOS:
I have a working shell script where I use the "date" command for logging:
$> date >> Log

This reports the following (dutch) when I execute the script from the termional window:
do 29 sep 2022 15:02:03 CEST

When I run this from cron I get:
Thu Sep 29 14:00:08 CEST 2022

How do I set the language and format to Dutch?

Comment: In general on a MAC I use gdate so that scripts are compatible with other platforms. this question is useful, not sure why it was marked down.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To set your current shell to a different language you use the bash variable LANG followed by the language you want:

```
LANG=nl_BE
```

If you want to set that so its used every time add an export line to your .bashrc for that user. The .bashrc file can be found in each user's homedir, if they don't have one you can create it:

```
export LANG=nl_BE
```

The command locale will show you information about locale on the server. The command locale -a will give you a list of all the locale you can use.

Comment: great, this works! Dank

Comment: @Rob consider to mark this response as a solution so others can trust it.